# PowerShell script speed standalone vs within Visual Code

Tags: powershell, performance, visual-studio-code

I have a simple PowerShell script that writes to a file a list of recently added files.

```
$fpath = "\\DS1821\video\movies"
$file1 = "C:\Users\brian.w.williams\Desktop\RecentMovie.txt"

if (Test-Path $file1) {Remove-Item -Path $file1}

Get-ChildItem -Path "$fpath" -File -Recurse -Include "*.eng.srt" |
ForEach-Object {

    $movie = $_.BaseName -replace ".eng",""

    if ( ($_.LastWriteTime.Month -ge 7) -and ($_.LastWriteTime.Year -ge 2021) ) {
        Write-Host $movie " = " $_.LastWriteTime
        Write-Output $movie | Out-file $file1 -append;
    }
    
}
```

The script works fine.  But I noticed that the script runs much faster (a couple of minutes) when run within Visual Code (i.e. "Run without debugging").  When I run the script standalone (i.e. "Run with PowerShell") the script can take hours to complete.  Why the difference?  Is there anything I can do to speed it up?  I have tried mapping the network folder, but that made no difference.

Comment: Sounds like you're experiencing the difference between Windows PowerShell 5.1 (the version that ships with Windows) and PowerShell 7 (the version that comes with the PowerShell extension for vscode).

Comment: While not related to speed performance, it would be better to create a platform independent path to the file. `$File1 = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop' -AdditionalChildPath 'RecentMovie.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

There is improvement to be made to help the code speed up.
First of all, using `Write-Host` and `Write-Output` to append to a file inside the ForEach loop is very time consuming.

Then you're using parameter `-Include` on Get-ChildItem, where you really want to use `-Filter`. A Filter is MUCH faster than Include, because the latter will only filter the filenames afterwards. `-Filter` however can only work on one single filename pattern, but this is exactly what you are doing here.

The `if(..)` can also be improved to have it compare only one value (a datetime) instead of two separate properties from LastWriteTime.

Try:

```
$sourcePath = '\\DS1821\video\movies'
# set a variable to an output file on your desktop
$outputFile = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath 'RecentMovies.txt'
# set the reference date in a variable for faster comparison later
$refdate    = (Get-Date -Year 2021 -Month 7 -Day 1).Date

# get the files, filter on the name ending in '*.eng.srt'
# filter more with Where-Object so you'll get only files newer than or equal to the reference date
# output objects with one calculated property ('MovieName') and the LastWriteTime
$movies = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File -Recurse -Filter '*.eng.srt' |
            Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $refdate } |
            Select-Object @{Name = 'MovieName'; Expression = {$_.BaseName -replace '\.eng\.srt$', '.srt'}},
                          LastWriteTime

# now output what you have collected to file. 
# Set-Content creates a new file or overwrites an existing file
$movies.MovieName | Set-Content -Path $outputFile

# and to screen
$movies | ForEach-Object { Write-Host ('{0} = {1}' -f $_.MovieName, $_.LastWriteTime.ToString()) }

# or to Out-GridView if you prefer
$movies | Out-GridView -Title 'My Movies'
```

<sup>1. I've changed some variable names to make the code better readable

2. Since `-replace` uses regex, you have to escape the dots with a backslash. The regex also anchors the string to the end of the BaseName with the dollar sign (`$`) at the end</sup>